# Are pursuing the well-being and reducing the suffering of sentient beings objectively good things?

Tags: ethics, consciousness, objectivity, happiness, axiom

I think most people intuitively agree that increasing their own well-being and minimizing their own suffering are the right things to do. Everyone wants to be happy, enjoy a good health, etc. The whole Maslow's hierarchy of needs is a thing for a reason. Some would go one step further and claim that not only our own well-being matters, but others' well-being matters too (thus supporting moral obligations toward other conscious beings, altruistic behavior, etc.). But in any case, the pursuit of well-being and the avoidance of suffering always appear to be at the core of any moral/ethical system if scrutinized deeply enough. Even a religious person who wants to go to Heaven and escape eternity in Hell could be said to be rationally justified in their preference based on the fact that Heaven will maximize their well-being and minimize their suffering, whereas Hell would be the polar opposite of that.

However, all of this relies on a fundamental axiom or premise, and that is that pursuing well-being and avoiding suffering are fundamentally good things to begin with. Are there any good reasons to assume that? Why not maximize suffering and minimize well-being instead (in which case "going to Hell" would be the optimum)? Are there objective reasons to consider the pursuit of well-being and the avoidance of suffering to be the *right things* to do?

Comment: In my opinion, the highest moral good is truth:  we should act to maximize and promote knowledge of important, true ideas, and refute false ones.  This is why sapient beings have a greater moral value than non-sapient beings.  Suffering in pursuit of the truth is no loss.  If we had a "mindless pleasure machine" that could provide lifelong pleasure to anyone using it, it would be harmful and immoral, because it would prevent people from using their lives to seek truth.

Comment: All knowledge is built on certain basic intuitions/axioms that are unprovable. My personal take is that we have a basic intuition that there's badness associated with suffering and goodness with lack of suffering. I'd classify this as knowledge of morality. I can't prove this axiom. Though I might be inclined to argue that all "moral talk" is meaningless without this basic idea.

Comment: The answer depends on whether one believes in moral objectivism (the most common form is [moral realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-realism/)), i.e. whether moral claims can be objective at all. Many do not believe they can, but see [Cuneo's Normative Web](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/the-normative-web-an-argument-for-moral-realism/) for an influential recent defense. Even if they can, "suffering" is an emotional category, and it is unclear that "sentient beings" must necessarily have emotions, so reducing it may not even be universally meaningful.

Comment: @causative what is an example of such attainable ideal truth?

Comment: "objectively good" is nonsense, "good" and "bad" are inherently subjective (like "ugly" but unlike "tall" or "straight" or "wet")

Comment: @Wottensprels For example, life knowledge, like "this is a good way to live."  Each person carries with them certain ideas and truths they live by - and they try to prove the validity of the truths that drive them.  Scientific or mathematical knowledge also.

Comment: @causative I disagree. Statements like "this is a good way to live" are 1) subjective and thus not based in an ideal and 2) subject to change and thus impossible to be an instance of eternal ideal truth. Scientific knowledge, too, is everything but universal and timeless. There is no "good way to live" that can not be called into question, so the statement that acting in order to "maximize and promote knowledge of important, true ideas, and refute false ones" is the highest moral good is a bit of a tautology.

Comment: @Wottensprels I think there are timeless truths embodied in the way people live.  "If you live this way, you get this kind of result."  Even though lives themselves are transient, the truths represented in those lives are eternal.  It is like the relationship between a calculation done on paper, and the timeless mathematical truth corresponding to that calculation.

Comment: Whereas I mostly agree that "Everyone wants to be happy, enjoy a good health, etc.", I do not accept that "most people intuitively agree that increasing their own well-being and minimizing their own suffering are the right things to do."  Self-sacrifice is very widely viewed as a virtue, and is very widely practiced to one degree or another.  We tend to view people who seek only their own good as dangerous, and maybe mentally ill.

Comment: I think the basic intuition mentioned wrt lack of suffering being good and suffering being bad is more or less hardwired into out DNA as one of the means / incentives to live economically. It all boils down to how one defines suffering (at the basest of levels it means lack of food and / or shelter). Also, while we consider self sacrifice a virtue, most of as will do exactly that, praise it instead of perform it, and the reason is also that it is in conflict with the DNA's #1 priority: keep the speciment alive

Comment: "the pursuit of well-being and the avoidance of suffering always appear to be at the core of any moral/ethical system if scrutinized deeply enough" - *Any* system? I think Kant would have issues with that assertion...

Comment: You seem to think well-being and lack of suffering go hand-in-hand. They could be polar opposites; exercising daily and eating a plant-based, alcohol-free diet are very good for well-being but not very pleasurable. Ditto the converse. This reductionism is doomed to failure...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the proposition IX, part III of *Ethics*, Spinoza operates the following reversal of concepts: it is not because we judge that something is good that we desire that thing, but it is because we desire it that we judge it to be good.

In Spinoza's philosophy, our judgement as well as our actions are entirely determined, based on what information and experience is available to us in the moment. The desire for a thing or state comes first, and it is by getting conscious of this desire that we form an opinion about their goodness or badness.

It also happens that living beings tend to desire what will keep them alive. It is self explanatory: all living creatures who didn't strive to stay alive just disappeared long time ago. Spinoza had no concept of evolution, but scientific findings long after his death corroborate his intuitions. The goal of this effort toward what keeps us alive is what you call "wellbeing".

The same reasoning can be applied to reducing suffering: our bodies tend to suffer under circumstances that threaten our health and life. Living beings who don't feel pain or feel it out of context tend to not avoid dangerous situations and die prematurely. This is where the prevalence of this instinct of pain avoidance comes from.

So, we desire well-being and dread suffering because this kept our species in the race for natural selection. And because we desire them, we assign them the label of "good", or conversely we assign the label "bad" to what we dread.

Comment: If you could choose between living forever in Heaven or living forever in Hell, which one would you choose? Both options are equal in terms of chances of survivability (you get eternal life in both cases), so you cannot differentiate them based on that aspect. Which one would you choose and why?

Comment: I happen to be a living being that just does not like to suffer, a bias inherited by my long ancestry of other living beings who survived thanks to it. So yeah, I would chose not to suffer even if I was immortal, because I simply don't like it. Now, nor heaven nor hell nor immortality exist as far as we know, so the question does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: *"So yeah, I would chose not to suffer even if I was immortal, because I simply don't like it"* - great, but would your preference for eternal bliss over eternal suffering be objectively justified? If in both cases there is perfect survivability, how can you objectively determine that one option is better than the other?

Comment: It would probably be a mere preference of mine, though my pain would be real, so choose not to endure it would objectively make sense to anyone, I guess. Again, this question's premice is so removed from reality that it just does not make sense to ask it. If we were totally not the person we are, our perspective on things would be different. So what ?

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator Given that we evolved in a world where an environment similar to that of hell would being lethal, the answer is clearly that anyone would choose to live somewhere other than _where the worm dieth not and the fire is never quenched_. If we evolved in a world where the heat of fire had no impact on survival, then there'd be no reason to avoid a place like hell.

Comment: I missed one crucial point, which is that in Spinoza's view objective good or bad do not exist. There are things that are good to me, bad to me, and those things can be respectively bad and good to someone else. So no objective positioning can be claimed about good or bad anyway. That does not mean good or bad is totally arbitrary: get shot in the head would be objectively bad to me.

Comment: @armand To me, getting shot in the head (assuming I died instantly) would be completely neutral since I'd never suffer. However, if I knew that I might get shot in the head, the anticipation would itself be suffering. So even something as "objectively bad" as death may not be to everyone.

Comment: @forest: I personally enjoy being alive and there are lots of stuff I'd still like to do, so I would certainly not consider being killed, even without any suffering or even not noticing it, to be neutral. But sure, people with terminal disease who can't enjoy life and suffer all day long do indeed sometime ask to be killed. To them, death is positive.

Comment: @armand But if you merely _stopped existing_, you would not even know. You would be unable to lament your inability to do things that you need to be alive to do.

Comment: @forest I totally agree, after my death I won't be able to lament. But right now, if someone asked me "how about I kill you in your sleep? you won't even feel it." my answer (and I guess, yours too) would be "I'd rather not to", because canceling all my potential happy plans is an idea that is negative to me, right now (and that's why I totally disagree with Epicurius, the idea that I won't be there to experience the state of being dead does not mean death or the process of dying is not to be feared)

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: "He who is unjust, let him be unjust still; he who is filthy, let him be filthy still; he who is righteous, let him be righteous still; he who is holy, let him be holy still." Revelations 22.11. "The mind is its own place and in itself, can make a Heaven of Hell, a Hell of Heaven." Milton. "We are not punished for our sins, but by them. " Elbert Hubbard. So, in this perspective, people do choose hell.

Answer (score 3):

Maximising wellbeing and avoiding suffering are just subjective heuristics required for evolution of replicating genes. A great deal of research shows things like having a job with autonomy is more important than higher pay, that a meaningful life connected to others is far more important than pleasure or suffering. We can relate moral progress to going beyond pleasure & pain as guides, and many philosophers do, like Aristotle's model of supervening layers of soul with uniquely human capacities supervening on our animal natures.

We might look to the value of living in a just society, as consistently being more important than personal wellbeing, to see how things like game-theory dynamics weigh heavier than momentary local or individual subjective measures of approval. Defining wellbeing requires a moral cosmology, to decide for instance whether access to abortions is a net positive or negative. That kind of fundamental dispute shows how wellbeing cannot be a guide, but is rather a value judgement in our wider picture of the world.

You might find this discussion relevant [Is the foundation of morality subjectively survival and happiness, and why or why not?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/76956/is-the-foundation-of-morality-subjectively-survival-and-happiness-and-why-or-wh/76980#76980)

Answer (score 2):

In light of your pre-assumed objective/subjective philosophical view, there're possibly several schools of thought to account for what's "good" for a person or a species. There's evolutionary naturalism or physicalism which suggests what's good for the person or as a species will be preserved and prevailed naturally, what's "bad" will be filtered out gradually and eventually. There's also idealism which may claim there's an ultimate creator who designs and creates all "good" properties immanent within any beings, and all those "good" aspects will unfold and manifest itself as time passes. If somehow the manifestation gets mistaken and confused by other factors, then it may not be "good", but its intrinsic designs will monitor and get this gradually and eventually in all perceived beings, such as those formulated by Leibniz's Monadology. Anyway, in all these classic views, we're quite confident to some degrees about what's "good", and what's "not good", at least in principle.

Some schools of thought may not accept your objective/subjective dualist view, and "good" and "suffering" are not opposite. In many religions, "suffering" is inevitable and universal, what's "good" may also be a type of "suffering". If you mainly accept subjective consciousness like Yogacara or Phenomenology, then "good" and "suffering" are both self-intuitive and innate characters, because here what can be discussed are only subjective phenomena. Just like in a dream, you can feel "good" and "suffering" there without any difficulty, just much weaker with much less free will (volition) compared with when awakened.

As for the application of quantum physics related philosophy, it may be more useful for philosophy of science or the like, may not fit to apply to ethics or personal suffering realm...

Answer (score 1):

Your question answers itself. *Well*-being implies the presence of goodness before anything else; asking if the pursuit of well-being is good is like asking if I will feel pain if I hurt myself.

But linguistics aside.

> however, all of this relies on a fundamental axiom or premise, and that is, that pursuing well-being and avoiding suffering are fundamentally good things to begin with.

Your problems begin even earlier. You can not objectively define what 'good' is supposed to mean. What hell is going to be like for you is dependent on you and nothing else. Perhaps you are suffering from a raging fear of spiders and your hell consists of being forced to live among tarantulas galore. An arachnologist will see things differently.

> But in any case, the pursuit of well-being and the avoidance of suffering always appear to be at the core of any moral/ethical system if scrutinized deeply enough

What *is* suffering? What is ethical? Should we permit euthanasia?
The reason such questions are loaded with enormous tensions is that they are ultimately unsolvable. What is well-being for one person will be a state of horrendous confinement for another.

What to make of it? Depends on you no less. At such a basic level, an answer will not be a lot more intellectual than that. You have to decide for yourself what the pursuit of well-being and the reduction of suffering may look like in action. But perhaps the more interesting question will be how you arrived at such conviction.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know what is "objectively good", because that would imply having the absolute truths required for something.

If something is good because it increases our probabilities of survival, then, "objectively good" implies knowing the absolute truths required to survive, which is impossible: all living beings follow its own *subjective truths* in order to survive, not an *objective truth* that is absolute and written somewhere in the universe.

It is only possible to have some truth as "subjectively good". Something that is good for one living being could be bad for another. For example, if lions would try to eat grass for survival, they would probably die. Each living being follows its own *subjective truths*.

You might argument that *good* is not related to survival. No problem. In such case, you can consider that killing people is good for the well-being of killers, but not for the well-being of buddist monks.

"The right things" are usually rules that people learn at home; that is, moral rules. And those are *cultural*, not absolute. Some cultures consider good to sacrifice animals, others consider animals sacred. Again, there's only possibility for "subjectively good".

Answer (score 0):

Oxford Languages (Philosophy) defines 'objective' as, "Not dependent on the mind for existence; actual".

If this definition is accurate, how can anything be objectively good or bad?

As far as we know, 'goodness' and 'badness' are mental constructs, entirely dependent on the mind.

One might be tempted to argue that whilst 'good' and 'bad' are human concepts, they *manifest* in the real world, in the absence of the language we give to them; but even if 'good' and 'bad' are equated with sensations like pleasure and pain, *minds* are required to experience them.

Answer (score -1):

Intuitively well-being and happiness are good things.  If we are going to say that something else is more important then we would need to identify what that is and justify why it’s more important.

Comment: Why should we trust our intuition? Quantum mechanics is arguably one of the least intuitive things we've discovered. Should we dismiss it because of that? But anyways, think of these two alternatives: 1) maximize well-being and 2) maximize suffering. Why would you say that 1 is **objectively** more important than 2?

Comment: At the risk of going off on a tangent, I suggest that quantum physics only seems non-intuitive because we are first taught about Newtonian physics.  Back on track though, what is important could be considered to be either objective, in which case we can determine what’s best and put the matter to rest, or subjective, in which case we can assert that our intuition is correct and the best thing is the one that we like the most.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator, QM builds on certain basic mathematical intuitions which are unproveable... we take them as axioms and move on. QM may be "counter-intuitive" but that is a different type of intuition. So there are two types of intuitions... the very basic one that is somehow impossible to deny... and higher level intuitions which may be denied. Although we may find QM counter-intuitive other people may not.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator, maximize suffering and you will die. People who maximize suffering tend to be naturally selected out, and those who maximize well being stay alive. That's an *objective* fact. Then after millions of years of this selection process being applied to animal instincts, we tend to see it as a natural, instinctive truth without really knowing why.

Comment: @armand - that would be an inductive argument based on correlation, but a robot without consciousness is incapable of experiencing well-being or suffering, so well-being doesn't even enter into the picture if the goal is to maximize a robot's survivability. Or conversely, you could imagine a situation where a person never dies (perfect survivability) but is constantly tortured (e.g. someone tortured eternally in hell). You get eternal survivability, yet maximum suffering.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that it's not hard to imagine scenarios where survivability and the conscious experience of either suffering or well-being are decoupled from each other.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator A sufficiently advanced robot can check up its internal status and determine if its integrity is in danger. For example sense that the light on its solar panel is too low and go to its base for electric charge. It's very crude, but this is its sense of well being. I wouldn't say it has no concept of it, just it has the concept that was designed by its creator. Note though that you are comparing two very different things, a robot being *designed* for a given mission, which we are not (as far as can we demonstrated).

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator, yes you can fantasize about anything, but does it have any touch with reality? How would someone be able to survive eternal torture? Have you ever seen anything resembling it? Realistic thoughts about how the world is working don't have to account for every fantasy people can have.

Comment: @armand - does your definition of well-being consider qualia? For example, can a philosophical zombie experience well-being or suffering under your definition of those terms?

Comment: It would really depend on how this person became a kind of demigod. If it's a person like you and me who suddenly made a pact with Zeus or something, they eod probably keep the bias we have against suffering in their brain. If it had always been such a powerful godly stuff, it would probably have no use for pain anyway and suffering would be a concept as strange to him as olive green is to a blind person. But then, you are again comparing us to something absolutely different.

Comment: @SpiritRealmInvestigator: a philosophical zombie would have to maintain their integrity just like we do, or they would all perish in a few days. So they would probably avoid damage, except without a qualia for pain. Damage would probably be to them a neutral information, like the damage status log displayed in Robocop's HUD display. Now the real question is, *why should I care about it, since no one has ever proved philosophical zombies do exist* (a bit like super duper immortal men, a problem that don't exist is not a problem).

Comment: "X is good" is not philosophy. This discussion is based in an opinion. Please move this to the chat.

Comment: Well-being and suffering are opinions.  I suggest it’s for the OP to decide whether I’ve answered their question.